# selecting two columns from multiple files and want to merge those column - column wise into one file

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am selecting two-columns (shown below) from multiple files, these columns will have an uneven number of rows..

```
   date         v1 
2020/08/06     220 
2020/08/06     2560 
....           ....  
....            ...
```

I have written code like this it merges all those two columns as row-wise but I want it column-wise.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import fnmatch

files1 = os.listdir('G:/Banknifty/2020/August/Expiry 06th August/')

pattern = '*CE.csv'
pattern1 = '*PE.csv'

matchce = fnmatch.filter(files1,pattern)
matchpe = fnmatch.filter(files1,pattern1)

path = 'G:/Banknifty/2020/August/Expiry 06th August/'

df = pd.DataFrame()

for m in matchce:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(path+m)
    dfs.columns = ['name', 'date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'v1']
    dfs.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df1 = dfs.loc['2020/08/06', 'v1']
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
    df = pd.concat([df1,df],axis=0,ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

I have tried using axis = 1 but it throws an error.

so How can I merge those columns in one file column-wise ??

I want like this,

```
 --File1 columns-   -file 2 columns-   -file 3- column-   ....
Date          v1     date       v1     Date       v1    Date        v1   ....
2020/08/06   220   2020/08/06  230   2020/08/06  250   2020/08/06  2600  ....
.....       ...     .....      ..     .....     ...    ....          .. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
df.stack().to_frame().reset_index(level=0,drop=True).T
```

Output:

```
         date   v1        date    v1
0  2020/08/06  220  2020/08/06  2560
```

Comment: will this do for each row ?? I want to start a new column after one file column gets done. 
 @Quang I have edited the post check out the last lines of the post.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of Index, it is done.

here is the code,

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import fnmatch

files1 = os.listdir('G:/Banknifty/2020/August/Expiry 06th August/')

pattern = '*CE.csv'
pattern1 = '*PE.csv'

matchce = fnmatch.filter(files1,pattern)
matchpe = fnmatch.filter(files1,pattern1)

path = 'G:/Banknifty/2020/August/Expiry 06th August/'

df = pd.DataFrame()

for m in matchce:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(path+m)
    dfs.columns = ['name', 'date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'v1']
    dfs.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df1 = dfs.loc['2020/08/06', 'v1']
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
    df=pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```